# Do all chars of a string belong to a set?

Tags: python, set

Is there a straightforward way of finding whether all characters of a string belong to a given set of characters? I have the following looping code that I feel can be shortened:

```
def allInSet(mystr, myset):
    result = True
    for char in mystr:
        result &= (char in myset)
    return result
```

Examples:

```
>>> allInSet("yyyow", set(['a','e','i','o','u','w','y']))
True
>>> allInSet("yowza", set(['a','e','i','o','u','w','y']))
False
```

also, `list(mystr) in set(['a','b','c'])` did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> set("aeiou").issuperset("hello world")
False
>>> set("aeiou").issuperset("eoo")
True
```